# How to test a rest service that uses a HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing

I'm trying to write a test for a rest service:

I have this post request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    ...
}
```

And I'm trying to test it using RestTemplate, but I couldn’t find any example where I can set the username in the HttpServletRequest.

Is there a solution at this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public String postToTest(String username) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("username", username);
    return restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/soa-server/user/", map, String.class);
}
```